# Ajax API Call access data on success call back, JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Why I can´t access Data like price, etc on the success of the call back. I get success response. I get the aggregated Data but somehow can´t access the value of price inside that array[aggregatedData]. Tried everything

```
function reqBitcoinData() {
        $.ajax({
            "url":"https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinsnapshot/?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD",
            "method": "get",
            "cache": false,
            "dataType": "JSON"
        }).done(function(jData) {
            console.log(jData);


            $.each(jData, function(i, jCurrency) {

                var AggregatedData = jCurrency.AggregatedData;

                aCurrencies.push(AggregatedData);

                console.log(AggregatedData);

            })


        }).fail(function(jFail) {
            console.log('Failed');
        })
    }
```

Comment: Where is `aCurrencies` defined and where are you trying to access it?

Comment: Share with us the output of `console.log(jData);`.

Comment: if the datatype is json then you would need to `JSON.parse(jData);` before iterating it.

Comment: @DLowther `dataType: json` in request parameters means that response data will be converted to json automatically.

Comment: Data
:
AggregatedData
:
FLAGS
:
"4"
FROMSYMBOL
:
"BTC"
HIGH24HOUR
:
"4356.45"
LASTMARKET
:
"Bitstamp"
LASTTRADEID
:
"22760100"
LASTUPDATE
:
"1507133382"
LASTVOLUME
:
"0.30955044"
LASTVOLUMETO
:
"1304.1050486759998"
LOW24HOUR
:
"4179.22"
MARKET
:
"CCCAGG"
OPEN24HOUR
:
"4278.63"
PRICE
:
"4221.48"
TOSYMBOL
:
"USD"
TYPE
:
"5"
VOLUME24HOUR
:
"59408.64828430318"
VOLUME24HOURTO
:
"253706110.19081962"

Comment: So it the `console.log` is working, you CAN access the data in the callback. Is your trouble that you can't access the data in the `aCurrencies ` array you're making? If so, where are you trying to access it. Outside the callback?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Prices :

```
  function reqBitcoinData() {
aCurrencies=[];
    $.ajax({
        "url":"https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinsnapshot/?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD",
        "method": "get",
        "cache": false,
        "dataType": "JSON"
    }).done(function(jData) {
        console.log(jData);
  var AggregatedData=jData.Data.AggregatedData;

  console.log(AggregatedData);
  //Price under AggregatedData
 var  Price=AggregatedData.PRICE;
 console.log(Price);

 //Prices under Exchanges 
        $.each(jData.Data.Exchanges, function(i, jCurrency) {

    aCurrencies.push(jCurrency.PRICE);
        })
console.log(aCurrencies);

    }).fail(function(jFail) {
        console.log('Failed');
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The response from the API is an object that contains Response, Message and Data. So you need to loop through the response.data like so:

```
function reqBitcoinData() {
    $.ajax({
        "url":"https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinsnapshot/?
fsym=BTC&tsym=USD",
        "method": "get",
        "cache": false,
        "dataType": "JSON"
    }).done(function(jData) {
        console.log(jData);


        $.each(jData.Data, function(i, jCurrency) {

            var AggregatedData = jCurrency.AggregatedData;

            aCurrencies.push(AggregatedData);

            console.log(AggregatedData);

        })


       }).fail(function(jFail) {
        console.log('Failed');
    })
  }
```

Comment: If my answer was helpful then why did you vote it down.

Comment: I did not @Mark Adesian. I only have 10 reputation so I cannot vote!. I appreciate your answer and wish I could give u the green check and upvote +1 sir